# Crystal Report? I am doing a simple summary that only needs 1 page of data. When running the report I am getting hundreds of duplicate pages?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

Am I doing something wrong? I get a large amount of duplicate pages. All I am doing is taking a sum of many columns, I do not need that repeated.

Essentially I am doing this.

In Details I have a bunch of columns.

Column A: Add up the sum of the database column Call Count.

Basically it will go through and count all the calls each user has placed.

Sum ({IAgentQueueStats.nAnsweredAcd})

I then set that to Text in another formula, I only want it visible once. I do not care that there are 20k records to display in my record filter.

But I need to have every record available to SUM up.

Comment: We can't tell if you're doing something wrong if you don't show us what you're doing.

Comment: There can be multiple issues...try checking your linking of tables which can produce duplicate records, if you are not sure of the table connections then select option `Select Distinct Records` in database menu which will only select distinct records.. Also where are you placing the variable where you are assiging the sum value.